# Converting key and pem certificates to p12 with OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, pem, p12

I am trying to convert two certificates files: .key and .pem to .p12 using OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey testcsr1.key -in wss-test.pem -out wss-test.p12
```

As a result I get error:
Loading 'screen' into random state - done

No certificate matches private key

I checked key file and it is PEM formatted. The file's content begins with -----BEGIN and it can be read in a text editor.

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#verify I should verify if private key matches certificate, so I did this with following commands:

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in testcsr1.key |openssl md5

openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in wss-test.pem | openssl md5
```

The hashes I received are different. What does this mean? wss-test.pem fie that I am using contains three certificates: my certificate, SubCA certificate and RootCA certificate, is this a problem?

Comment: Yes `x509` only loads the first cert in the file, I imagine the same is for `pkcs12`, simply separate your file into separate files.

Comment: @mnistic: yes `x509` does only first cert, although by convention the EE cert (if any) _is_ usually first. To split see https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle/ and its linked Qs and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366898/generate-hpkp-fingerprints-for-all-certificate-chain . No `pkcs12` is not the same; I'll bet right now none of the certs in the file matches.